# Why using TEXT_MATCH is too slow in carbondata table?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, lucene, carbon-data

I ve created table with spark-sql

```
CREATE TABLE my_hdfs_schema.test_table
(
name string,
Lname string
)
PARTITION ( day string )
AS carbondata
```

And i ve created **lucene** index

```
CREATE INDEX ind_lucene_test ON TABLE
 my_hdfs_schema.test_table 
( name )
AS 'lucene'
```

Then insert data

```
Insert into my_hdfs_schema.test_table
Select * from    mynoncarbontablewithsameschema
Where day 
between '20200101' 
and '20240101'
```

Then when i select like this

```
Select * from
my_hdfs_schema.test_table
Where day = '20231231' 
and name like 'test%'
```

It gets data in **30** secs ( it s not really fast same as spark select with noncarbon table time )

When i select like this

```
Select * from 
my_hdfs_schema.test_table
Where TEXT_MATCH('name:test*')
And day ='20231231'
```

It never gets data back
It stucks

When i see the spark process on ui i see it leverages one task and waits

I use spark with my yarn cluster

How can i handle this ?